# magento API with .net c# exception when creating shopping cart

Tags: c#, asp.net, magento-1.7

So, I've been trying to integrate my existing ASP .net web application with Magento web store. I can add new products to the catalog, but ran into a myriad of problems.
All I'm trying to do is create a new shopping cart and add a customer from my existing customer list to it and add some products it the cart before creating an order from the shopping cart.

The code below results in EXCEPTION: "The customer's identifier is not valid or customer is not existed." Please tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can process this. I just need to create a new order for a product I have in the catalog.

```
cartID = mage.shoppingCartCreate(mageSessionID, "");
MageService.customerCustomerEntity[] custs = mage.customerCustomerList(mageSessionID, filter1);
MageService.shoppingCartCustomerEntity custom = new shoppingCartCustomerEntity();
custom.customer_id = custs[0].customer_id;
custom.firstname = custs[0].firstname;
custom.lastname = custs[0].lastname;
custom.email = custs[0].email;
custom.website_id = custs[0].website_id;
custom.store_id = custs[0].store_id;
custom.mode = "customer";
Boolean cartFlag = mage.shoppingCartCustomerSet(mageSessionID,cartID, custom, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an old question that was never answered, I ran into same problem. There is no documentation anywhere to allude to the solution/fix. I have found it and feel it worthy to still answer this old question for others who come across.

If you are setting the customer id, you also need to set customer_idSpecified to TRUE.

Then it works.

In your code above it would be:

```
custom.customer_idSpecified = custs[0].customer_idSpecified;
```

Hope you've figured it out at this point.

Shane